# Send a key to WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

**Short Version:** Is it possible to send a key press event to an embedded `WebView` in `Windows Phone`?

**Long Version:**
I have a simple `HTML5` game hosted on a website and now I want to load it inside a `WebSite` in a `Windows Phone` app and then add control keys (e.g. left, right, shoot) to the button of the screen. And then, if the user pressed the *left* button, I would send a *left* key to the `WebView`. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can be executed in the WebView using [`WebView.InvokeScriptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx). You should be able to use it to call the same JavaScript event handler methods you use for key events.

Also note that `InvokeScriptAsync` only invokes a single JavaScript function, however if you need to execute an arbitrary number of statements, a neat trick is to use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). For example:

```
var script = "...";
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
```